# Invalid target release on Maven project when pushing to heroku repository

Tags: java, maven, heroku

Upon pushing a spring boot maven project to a Heroku repository, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project userservice: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17
```

I have created a `system.properties` file in the root directory of my spring boot app and added `java.runtime.version=17` to it but still no luck.

I have a similar issue than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034974/heroku-system-properties-and-java-version) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012401/invalid-target-release-12-when-pushing-the-heroku-repo) question and followed the solutions but it did not work for me.

Comment: Does your Procfile point out your target release?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/userservice-1.0.jar` inside my Procfile, where `userservice` and `1.0` are the artifact id and version specified in my pom.xml respectively.

Comment: I think you should package your project as WAR.

Comment: That didn't work too

Comment: This `invalid target release: 17` you are not using a JDK17...no property etc. will help here..

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I've resorted to the heroku maven plugin directly and specified the requirements in the pom.xml directly. It now works.